# how to using recursive function correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I make a function  used to return string with string value like this: "not aritmatic". But when I recursive my function to controll another action, my recursive function not work. how to  doing recursive correctly in javascript?

```
//call function  ArithGeo
ArithGeo([2, 4, 6, 8, 12]);
//build function  ArithGeo
function ArithGeo(arr) {
    var copy_arr = arr;
    var array_selisih = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
        array_selisih[i] = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
    }
    var j = 0;

    var x = array_selisih[0];
    if (arr.length % 2 == 1) {
        for (j = 0; j <= array_selisih.length - 2; j++) {
            //alert(array_selisih[x]+":"+array_selisih[j]);
            if (array_selisih[x] != array_selisih[j]) {
                return 'notaritmatic';
            }
        }
    } else if (arr.length % 2 == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j <= array_selisih.length - 3; j++) {
            // alert(array_selisih[x]+":"+array_selisih[j]);
            if (array_selisih[x] != array_selisih[j]) {
                return 'notaritmatic';
            }
        }
    }
    return "aritmatik";
    //my problem is here
    if (ArithGeo(copy_arr) == "notaritmatic") {
        //do something when return value is not aritmatic string
        alert('not aritmatic ok');
    }
}
```

I am  sorry if my algorithm is long, I just try to sharpen my skill to solve problem with own idea. -_-
https://jsfiddle.net/fwdgmvyw/

Comment: Unreachable code. Statement following `return "aritmatik";` will never be executed.

Comment: sorry I am forget to change that before post my question, i wanna show you my code  in jfidle please wait me..

Comment: What do mean by `notaritmatic`? Do you want to check element is a number or not?

Comment: no, I really make a function to check if  a sequence is arithmatic, this is I mean http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Arith%20Geo&lan=JavaScript

Comment: There's no scope for recursion in the given code. You're passing an array to your method which after evaluating it returns an output. There's no room for going to any nth level. The check that you have added after the return should be done at the very top where the call to the method is made.

Comment: Can you teach me the right way, this is my complete  source code https://jsfiddle.net/fwdgmvyw/?

Comment: Is there even a need of recursion to check if a series is an arithmetic or geometric progression ? It can be done with just some loops.

Comment: Do you really need a recursive function, or are you doing this out of curiosity?

Sometimes the easiest way to arrive at a recursive function can be to start writing it out in the long form as a series of manual calls to a simpler function until you see the actual pattern you need to recurse over. You may find that a loop is easier.

I would suggest using a method you are more familiar with first, write some unit tests to show that it works as you expect and then try to convert it to a recursive function that passes the same unit tests.

Comment: I believe that my way is correct. if the recursive trick can runing in program..

Comment: you are right Klors, i just make an experimen, am I wrong  to do that?

Comment: No, curiosity is good :)

Comment: I actually could solve this problem by making some functions and joining them one by one, but I think recursion can be faster to use.